# Создание tar-архива для переноса файлов c devel на production

Tags: linux, tar

1. Имеется список файлов для переноса на боевой сервер с devel в виде:

   bitrix/php_interface/include/functions.php
   local/components/portal/basket.full/templates/.default/script.js
   local/components/portal/manager.avatar/templates/.default/template.php
   local/components/portal/order/component.php
   local/components/portal/order/templates/.default/template.php
   local/components/portal/user.data_block/component.php
   local/components/portal/user.data_block/templates/.default/style.css
   local/components/portal/user.data_block/templates/.default/template.php

По этому списку необходимо создать tar-архив с созданием структуры каталога.

2. Далее данный архив необходимо разархивировать на продакшне таким образом, чтобы он заменил соответствующие файлы в каталоге.

Вопрос: какими командами можно это всё сделать?

Comment: А папки `bitrix` и `local` в одно директории находятся?

Comment: Да, они находятся в одной директории

Comment: а в чём сложности-то? это ж самое базовое и умолчальное, для чего используется программа *tar*: 1. `$ tar -cf архив путь1/файл1 путь2/файл2 ...` 2. `$ tar -xf архив`

Comment: *man rsync*, намного лучше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это же самый обычный сценарий использования программы *tar*:

1. упаковка:

   ```
   $ tar -cf архив путь/к/файлу1 путь/к/файлу2 ...
   ```

   именно, так, с указанными путями, файлы и будут сохранены в архиве.
2. распаковка:

   ```
   $ tar -xf архив
   ```

---

программа *tar* по умолчанию работает с текущим каталогом. именно относительно текущего каталога будут «вычисляться» указанные относительные пути.

но с помощью опции `-C путь` можно указать программе, чтобы она работала не с текущим, а с указанным каталогом. это можно указать и при упаковке и при распаковке.

---

а если у вас есть ssh-доступ к серверу, то можно даже и архив не создавать:

```
$ tar -C /локальный/каталог/ -c путь/к/файлу1 ... | ssh машина tar -C /каталог/на/сервере -x
```

---

ну и список файлов можно не в командной строке перечислять, а указать файл, этот список содержащий, с помощью опции `-T файл`:

```
$ tar -cf архив -T путь/к/файлу/со/списком
```

Answer (score 1):

для запаковки:

```
tar --directory='/path/to/patch' -caf project_patch.tar --files-from='list_of_files_for_pack.txt'
```

для распаковки:

```
tar --overwrite -xaf project_patch.tar --directory='/path/to/project'
```

`--directory=` можно заменить на `-C`
`--files-from=` на `-T`

Comment: а зачем `-a`? а зачем `--overwrite`?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin `--overwrite` "чтобы он заменил соответствующие файлы в каталоге."  `-a` что-бы не морочиться с расширением архива, таким образом можно в качестве архива указать как `aprch.tar` так и `arch.tar.gz` как при упаковке так и при распаковке

Comment: я, конечно, в курсе, для чего эти опции служат. я спрашивал — зачем они в ответе. 1. программа *gnu/tar* и так по умолчанию **заменяет**, поэтому в отсутствие других опций из секции «overwrite control» опция `--overwrite` не имеет смысла. 2. а опция `-a` не имеет смысла ввиду конкретного указания вами имени файла с архивом.

Comment: @Andrey Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком формате должен быть список файлов для архива? Передаю ему такой список:

bitrix/php_interface/include/functions.php
local/components/portal/manager.avatar/templates/.default/template.php
local/components/portal/order/templates/.default/template.php

При запаковке возвращается ошибка:

Comment: tar: bitrix/php_interface/include/functions.php\r: Функция stat завершилась с ошибкой: Нет такого файла или каталога
tar: local/components/portal/manager.avatar/templates/.default/template.php\r: Функция stat завершилась с ошибкой: Нет такого файла или каталога
tar: local/components/portal/order/templates/.default/template.php\r: Функция stat завершилась с ошибкой: Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: Причем при таком формате команды: tar -cf lk_patch.tar bitrix/php_interface/constants.php bitrix/php_interface/dev_tools.php

ошибок не возникает.

Comment: Похоже, что ошибка возникает из-за символа переноса каретки \r